# How can I show and hide elements in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

I need to get a site working in the dreaded IE down to 8 unfortunately - Its a long time since I had to do anything with 8 so I'm struggling with the following.

I'm using a `Modernizr Check` which runs the following script for an old browser:

```
$(".hp_header #bgvid, .hp_header .cd-background-wrapper").hide();
$(".hp_header .respy").show();
$(".hp_header #bgvid, .hp_header .cd-background-wrapper").css("display", "none");
$(".hp_header .respy").css("visible", "true");
$(".hp_header .respy").css("display", "block");
$(".hp_header .respy").css("width", "100%");
```

Unfortunately the visibility and display options are completely ignored by IE8, what should I do?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What part of it isn't working? What is the DOM this code is meant to run against?

Comment: ***If*** `.respy` is an element that defaults to `inline-block` or `inline` (such as `span`), you can't make IE8 treat it as `block`. That's just the reality of old IE. Also note that there is no `visible` CSS property (there's `visibility`, but it doesn't have a `true` value, it has `visible`, `hidden`, or `collapse`).

Comment: [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) and [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) work all the way back to IE4, so you shouldn't have any issues. Can you describe exactly what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you're looking for but more of a suggestion.
You could use conditional html statements like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
```

Then, you could do everything is css like this :

```
.ie8 .hp_header #bgvid, 
.ie8 .hp_header .cd-background-wrapper {
    display:none;
}

.ie8 .hp_header .respy {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    visibility:visible;
}
```